# Paypal creating account return unverified

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I would like to ask with you if you were experience this kind of situation.

I'm using express checkout api and I successfully submitted my payment if the client has already an account in paypal. It returns verified but my problem is. If the client doesn't have an account. The client needs to create an account in paypal (just like the image below)[image]

But when the client successfully create an account and continue the transaction.

Why is it the paypal status return unverified? 
Is this not applicable in sandbox about creating paypal account?

But when I check my merchant account. It is successfully paid. I just want clear my mind about this. I'm new in paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An account is not verified until they add a bank account and verify that bank account with PayPal.  If they're creating the account on the fly during checkout then that part is probably just not getting done before they complete their payment with you.

Comment: thanks for your reply @andrew angell. Why is it I still receive the payment of my client while the status is unverified? I'm sorry, I really don't understand how the paypal work when it comes to unverified the status.

Comment: An account doesn't have to be verified to make payments with it.  They could have added a credit card and funded it that way, which is probably what was done.